# jquery paste event not firing if pasted using context menu in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

How to detect paste event, if it is triggered by chrome context menu ? 
If done using `ctrl + V`

following works fine.

```
 $('#txtNumbers').on('keyup paste change', function () {

            if ($(this).val() !== '') {
                $('#btnAdd').prop('disabled', false);
            }
            else {
                $('#btnAdd').prop('disabled', true);
            }
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `input` event

```
 $('#txtNumbers').on('input', function () {

            if ($(this).val() !== '') {
                $('#btnAdd').prop('disabled', false);
            }
            else {
                $('#btnAdd').prop('disabled', true);
            }
  });
```